# Discord.py bot repeating the command

Tags: discord.py, bots

Hey I am creating a discord bot using python I have put my first command it says pong but have edit that command and run the bot again and for checking I put the command ping the pong is repeated 2-3 times. This only my 1st command I have use I want to add more command then this issue I will face again plss help if someone is having to fix this thanks

Comment: Can you include your code in the question?

Comment: If you're running the bot in an IDE (like vscode or pycharm) you might be running multiple instances of the script, simply close and open again the IDE, you can also open the task manager (`Ctrl + Shift + Esc`) and kill all python processes.

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot('!') # ! is Prefix

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is Online!")

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("pong")

@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hello")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```